# C# список для хранения произвольных классов

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день. 
Возникла следующая задача.
Имеется несколько произвольных классов, они могут наследовать от одного базового класса, а могут не наследовать. Задача завести некий список, в котором будет хранится последовательность создания этих классов с возможностью добавления в произвольное место новых классов. Хотелось бы узнать у более опытных товарищей, как это лучше реализовать в C#. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Наглядней покажите какие типы вам нужно хранить

Comment: В один список можно класть только то, что имеет общее. В самом примитивном случае можно использовать массив Object (все наследуется от него). Ну или Dynamic (если против него нет предубеждений). Проблема в том, что без "целей создания списка" и как следствие без понимания, что и как с вложенными классами  планируется делать.... На ваш вопрос никто не ответит)

Comment: @Вадим Ну два комментария уже есть)  А про Object, спасибо, что напомнили, совсем про него забыл, давно не щупал C#, все на OpenEdge программирую. Dynamic не трогал, посмотрю, опять спасибо. А классы пока показать не могу, еще не до конца сформировал концепцию проекта.

Comment: Ко всем этим классам добавить общий интерфейс.

Comment: Да не за что) Просто обычно, списки классов создают не для того чтобы они были) А для того чтобы с ними можно было что то сделать. А вот тут у object появляются проблемы. Ибо "Надо приводить?", "А во что надо приводить?". Как следствие если честно, подобных хранилищ я не видел). Но если идея понравилась, то я рад.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо, где-то на краю памяти вертелось, что можно провернуть это через наследование.)

Comment: Ну, можно взять древний `System.Collections.List` (необобщённый). Но скорее всего вам это не нужно. Расскажите, для чего вам понадобился список разнородных объектов, что вы с ним собираетесь делать?

Comment: "Последовательность создания классов"? Уж не `List<Type>` ли вам нужен?

Comment: Посмотрите  DataContractSerializer напр тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073(v=vs.110).aspx